# Firebase messaging issue when app is in foreground on Ionic 5 app

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am following the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs?gclid=Cj0KCQjwna2FBhDPARIsACAEc_UPil0kBA7kKtglpx2fdztTiYiQkl9ld9br71meoGGyEZRLd1hAM1IaAqaiEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) for implementation of Cloud Messgaing.
Receiving and handling messages while my ionic app is in the background works fine but when handling same in foreground I am running into issues.

This is the code:

```
PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationReceived',
    (notification : PushNotificationSchema) => {
      alert("Push received while app open: " + JSON.stringify(notification));
      

      const title = notification.notification.title;
      const body = notification.notification.body;
      const page = notification.notification.data.department;

      alert ("Notification: department =  " + page + " Title : " + title);
      //console.log("NOTIFICATION  REC IN APP FOREGROUND: " + title + " AND BODY : " + body);

     
      if (page){
        this.router.navigate(['/'+page]);
      }
    },
    );
```

The first alert with details of the notification  executes every time, but nothing after.
In the Xcode console I see an error but there is no description:

[image]

Any idea what the issue might be with my ionic code or how to determine the error thrown in Xcode would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is helpful for some as I found there are allot of potential  answers out there but the only solution I found is as follows:

Add this to the capacitor.config.json of your Ionic project:

```
"plugins": {
  "PushNotifications": {
    "presentationOptions": ["badge", "sound", "alert"]
  }
}
```

Then build / synch your ionic app:

```
ionic build
ionic cap sync
```

See Capacitor [Docs here](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config) for more details.